# Mixing standard and lazy evaluation of function arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

## Actual question

How can I mix standard and lazy evaluation of function arguments while giving the user a **unified** and **simple** syntax when calling my functions?

## Background

I'm a huge fan of `dplyr`, but what I don't quite like about it is that it makes you use distinguish function names (e.g. `select` vs. `select_`) and that it makes you think too much of how to write function calls when you want to express your arguments as a "mixed bag": some are expressed as character strings, for others you want lazy evaluation, for yet others you want standard evaluation. Also see John Mount's [blog post on wrapr](https://www.r-bloggers.com/wrapr-for-sweet-r-code/) for another example of where it becomes overly complex to do a simple thing due to standard vs. lazy evaluation.

## Example

This is the simplest way of writing my `dyplyr::select` expression that I know of

```
x <- "disp"
select_(mtcars, "mpg", ~cyl, x)
```

After playing around, here's a draft of the solution I'm after:

```
select2 <- function(dat, ...) {
  args <- substitute(list(...))

  ## Express names as character //
  idx <- which(sapply(args, class) == "name")[-1]
  ## We don't care about the first one as it's going to be
  ## substituted anyway
  if (length(idx)) {
    for (ii in idx) args[[ii]] <- as.character(args[[ii]])
  }
  ## Ensure `c()` //
  args[[1]] <- quote(c)

  ## Standard eval for variables containing actual column name //
  idx <- which(!eval(args) %in% names(dat)) + 1
  if (length(idx)) {
    for (ii in idx) args[[ii]] <- eval(as.name(args[[ii]]))
  }

  ## Indexing expression //
  exprsn <- substitute(dat[, J], list(J = eval(args)))
  eval(exprsn)
}

x <- "disp"
(select2(mtcars, "mpg", cyl, x))
```

It works, but of course it's very poorly implemented with regard to efficiency ;-)

To make it better and to understand more with regard to evaluation in R, in particular I'd like to know how to get rid of the `for` loops and how I could best leverage existing functionality of the `dplyr` and `lazyeval`packages as well as base-R functionality like `do.call("[.data.frame", ...)`, `with()` or the like. Especially the indexing and assignment methods (`"[.*"` and `"<-.*"`) and how to call them directly are still kind of a mystery for me.

Comment: Why the `eval(x)` in the `select_`?  Using `x` alone should work.

Comment: @JakeKaupp That's true, I changed it

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loops? You could replace `for (ii in idx) args[[ii]] <- as.character(args[[ii]])` with `args[[idx]] = lapply(args[[idx]], as.character)`, but it won't change anything from an efficiency perspective...

Comment: @Gregor I usually stop and think "there must be a better solution" when I use for loops and "better" usually means making use of vectorized operations somehow. So I guess what I was trying to say is "how do I make this entire thing faster and/or reduce the code I need to get me from A to B" :-)

Comment: It's rare to find vectorized solutions when you're no longer working within vectors.